# 1 Corinthians 10:13; are there temptations beyond such as is common to man? If there are, then, where are they mentioned in the Holy Bible?

Tags: 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 10:13; DRB;

> 13 Let no temptation take hold on you, **but such as is human.** And God is faithful, who will not suffer you to be tempted above that which you are able: but will make also with temptation issue, that you may be able to bear it.

1 Corinthians 10:13; KJV;

> 13 There hath no temptation taken you **but such as is common to man:** but God is faithful, who will not suffer you to be tempted above that ye are able; but will with the temptation also make a way to escape, that ye may be able to bear it.

Are there temptations above (beyond) Human?=beyond( Such as is common to man)?, If there are, then, where are they mentioned in the Holy Bible?

Comment: A temptation level isn't the point. It's the *common fate of men* to be tempted by evil. In other words, it's normal for a human to struggle against evil - none are exempt and it is to be expected - as a human in this age. (There is only one source of evil - in heaven or earth)

Comment: That is a questionable translation. (It is from the Latin Vulgate, in any case.) _There hath no temptation taken you but such as is common to man:_ [KJV]. _No temptation hath taken you -- except human_ [Young's Literal] _No temptation has taken you except what is human;_ [Green's Literal] The hypothetical question of 'temptations beyond human' simply does not arise with the standard translations (from Greek).

Comment: @Dottard The question's difficulty (made by the DRB) is 'Let no ...' as if there is an option. The 'option' is then assumed to be 'human or not human ?' which is ridiculous. The proper translation is a past tense 'has not taken'. There is not future option of . . .  'let'. It is a _non sequitur_ : a non question.

Answer (score 1):

We must recall that the DRB is not a translation of the Greek but is a translation of the Latin which translates the Greek; thus, it is a translation of a translation.

Despite this, in 1 Cor 10:13 it give a very literal meaning of the Greek.  Here is my literal translation of the Greek:

> πειρασμὸς ὑμᾶς οὐκ εἴληφεν εἰ μὴ **ἀνθρώπινος** ... = no temptation
> has seized you if not **human** ...

The literal meaning here is that we all subject to the usual human temptations that prey upon our human weaknesses.  Most version provide a smoothed out and somewhat interpretive translation by saying something like:

- No temptation has seized you except what is **common to man** ...

While such a translation is not explicit it is strongly implied in Paul's typically terse, word-economic style.

Barnes is comforting about this verse:

> **But such as is common to man** - εἰ μὴ ἀνθρώπινος ei mē anthrōpinos. Such as is "human." Margin, "Moderate." The sense is
> evident. It means such as human nature is liable to, and has been
> often subjected to; such as the human powers, under the divine aid may
> be able to resist and repel. The temptations which they had been
> subjected to were not such as would be suited to angelic powers, and
> such as would require angelic strength to resist; but they were such
> as human nature had been often subjected to, and such as man had often
> contended with successfully. There is, therefore, here a recognition
> of the doctrine that man has natural ability to resist all the
> temptations to which he is subject; and that consequently, if he
> yields, he is answerable for it. The "design" of the apostle is to
> comfort the Corinthians, and to keep their minds from despondency. He
> had portrayed their danger; he had shown them how others had fallen;
> and they might be led to suppose that in such circumstances they could
> not be secure. He therefore tells them that they might still be safe,
> for their temptations were such as human nature had often been subject
> to, and God was able to keep them from falling.

Meyer has a useful note as well:

> **ἀνθρώπινος** i.e. viribus humanis accommodatus, οὐχ ὑπὲρ ὃ δύναται ἄνθρωπος. See Pollux, iii. 131. The fact that in the second clause of
> the verse this phrase has ὑπὲρ ὃ δύνασθε and τοῦ δύνασθαι ὑπενεγκεῖν
> corresponding to it, militates against the rendering: “not of
> superhuman origin”

However, we should never divorce the first part of the verse from its second half - humanly speaking, we are extremely bad at resisting temptation, but the second half of the verse provides assurance by saying:

> **God is faithful**, and he will not let you be tempted beyond your ability, but with the temptation he will also provide the way of
> escape, that you may be able to endure it.

Gill comments on this as follows:

> **but God is faithful**, who will not suffer you to be tempted above that ye are able: no man can be tempted, afflicted, or persecuted by
> men, but by a divine permission, and that voluntary; nor more than, or
> above that measure which God hath determined; who proportions the
> affliction to the strength he determines and promises to give, and
> does give, and the strength of his people to the temptation or
> affliction he suffers to befall them; for which his faithfulness is
> engaged, having promised that as their day is, their strength shall
> be; that he will never leave them nor forsake them, and that he will
> bear, and carry, and save them unto the uttermost, and that they shall
> hold on and out unto the end: